# SingleOrDefault() throws a NullReferenceException in F#

Tags: f#

The code below throws a NullReferenceException within the `FirstOrDefault()` method:

```
open System
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Linq

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let suspects = seq {
        yield ("Frank", 1.0)
        yield ("Suzie", 0.9)
        yield ("John", 0.5)
        // yield ("Keyser Soze", 0.3)
    }
    let likely = suspects.FirstOrDefault(fun (name, confidence) -> name = "Keyser Soze")
    printfn "Name: %s" (fst likely)
    Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
    0
```

What's the best way to work around that? Catching it seems wrong. I could grab the iterator manually and put it in a while loop, but that's - well, wrong on so many levels.

[Edit]
I can't even do what I would do in C#, namely, check to see if the result is null or default, for two reasons: (1) The error is thrown in the `FirstOrDefault()` method, not when I reference the result; and (2) if I try to check for null, the compiler complains that `The type '(string * float)' does not have 'null' as a proper value':

```
    if likely = null then            
        printfn "Nothing to see here"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it FirstOrDefault or SingleOrDefault ?

Comment: Check for null, just as you would in C# (assuming FirstOrDefault)..?

Comment: @Habib - Doesn't matter. Behave the same way.

Comment: @ildjarn - Can't check for null. If you try, it won't compile. The exception is thrown in the `FirstOrDefault()` method, not in referencing the result afterwards. That's because the tuple type that it returns can't be null.

Comment: @KenSmith, `SingleOrDefault` would raise an exception if there are multiple elements found against a condition, Shouldn't be a problem with your code.

Comment: You can use `obj.ReferenceEquals` to check for null, but you should really be using `Seq.tryFind` anyway.

Comment: @ildjarn - There we go. `Seq.tryFind` is what I was looking for. Thanks! Throw it in an answer and I'll give you credit :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted above, `Seq.tryFind` is the idiomatic way of achieving that.  If you really must use `FirstOrDefault()` you could do something like this:

```
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Linq
let suspects = seq {
    yield Some("Frank", 1.0)
    yield Some("Suzie", 0.9)
    yield Some("John", 0.5)
    // yield ("Keyser Soze", 0.3)
}
let likely = suspects.FirstOrDefault(fun x -> let name, confidence = x.Value
                                              name = "Keyser Soze")
match likely with
| Some(x) -> printfn "Name: %s" (fst x)
| None -> printfn "Not Found"
```

Comment: Nice tip there about changing the type of the sequence to `seq<(string * float) option>`. But in this case, `Seq.tryFind()` works just fine. Thanks.

Comment: @KenSmith Right.  This is just a way of hacking `FirstOrDefault` such that it works pretty much the same as `Seq.tryFind()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow hardcode null checks-polluted C# way if you want to:

```
...
let likely = suspects.FirstOrDefault(fun x -> x.Equals(null) || (fst x) = "Keyser Soze")
if obj.ReferenceEquals(likely, null) then
    printfn "Nothing to print"
else
    printfn "Name: %s" (fst x)
...
```

but this is against the major F# idiom upon avoiding null-checks altogether.

**EDIT:** It seems the alleged `NullReferenceException` within `FirstOrDefault` actively referred in comments simply does not happen! With first line of code above changed back to the original

```
let likely = suspects.FirstOrDefault(fun (name, confidence) -> name = "Keyser Soze")
```

the snippet works for the sequence of three first tuples without a problem.

Comment: Good point about how to check for null. But in my example above, it wouldn't ever get to that line, as the exception was thrown in the `suspects.FirstOrDefault()` call.

Comment: @KenSmith: In the suggested workaround `suspects.FirstOrDefault()` does not throw an exception upon exosting the sequence in absense of sought criterion as it performs the dreaded `null` argument check and does not perform string comparison, if this is the case.

Comment: I believe the problem is that the F# tuple type doesn't have a default and this is causing `FirstOrDefault()` to throw an exception if the lambda passed to it results `false`.  As such, any checks which occur after `FirstOrDefault()` is done will be inadequate.

Comment: @mydogisbox : `System.Tuple<>` is a reference type and thus has a default value of `null`, as with all reference types. You just can't check for `null` with `=` or `<>` in this case.

Comment: @ildjarn I was referring to this: `let (tuple:int*int) = null`  `error FS0043: The type '(int * int)' does not have 'null' as a proper value`  Since `likely` is a tuple, F# doesn't recognize `null` as a valid value.

Comment: @mydogisbox : But there's always `let tuple:int*int = Unchecked.defaultof<_>` and `if obj.ReferenceEquals (tuple, null) then`. Leaky abstractions, maybe, but still... ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn ew... EW!  Don't show me these things!